# Altering an SSAS Calculated Measure depending on depth of drill down into dimension hierarchy

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

A cut down version of the fact table columns are:

```
id [substitute Pk guid], TestNo, DrugGroupId, Positive
```

where DrugGroupId references a Measure table 
id, DrugGroup, Drug, Result

The Positive column is defined as

```
when Result != 'negative' then 1 else 0
```

Examples of the DrugGroup would be

- [guid], Amphetamines, Amphetamines, negative
- [guid], Amphetamines, amphetamine, amphetamine
- [guid], Amphetamines, methamphetamine, methamphetamine
- [guid], Cannabinoids, Cannabinoids, Negative
- [guid], Cannabinoids, Cannabinoids, Positive

I have a calculated Measure, a simple ratio between Sum(Postive) and the fact table Count

```
[Measures].[Positive] / [Measures].[Count]
```

However the quirk of my data is that any given TestNo in the fact table does not have just one row.

So if the result is a negative there is 1 row, however some drugs will have multiple postive rows, one for each "Drug" under the "DrugGroup"
So if the data were denormalised into one table it would look like

- [guid], Test1, Amphetamines, Amphetamines, negative
- [guid], Test2, Amphetamines, methamphetamine, methamphetamine
- [guid], Test2, Amphetamines, amphetamine, amphetamine
- [guid], Test1, Cannabinoids, Cannabinoids, positive
- [guid], Test2, Cannabinoids, Cannabinoids, negative

note that a 'Positive" "Drug" is only allowed when there is not detailed breakdown of that "DrugGroup" (i.e. Cannabis)

Given the example data above, my Ratio measure (using a hierarchy) would calculate (displayed in a SharePoint Performance Point Analytic Grid Report)

- [DrugGroup,Drug,Result], Positive, Count, Ratio
- [All], 3, 5, 60%
- [Amphetamines], 2, 3, 33%
- [amphetamine], 1, 1, 100%
- [methaphetamine], 1, 1, 100%
- [Cannabinoids], 1, 2, 50%
- [Cannabinoids], 1, 2, 50%

As you can see, the Ratio is calculated incorrectly at the "DrugGroup" level as multiple positives are over counted and at the "Drug" level I only ever get 100% for drugs unless their results are "pos/neg" only.

How do I either structure that data so that the results will be calculated correctly when rolled up or create a ratio measure that can sort out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

- As I am interested in a count of distinct TestNo's, I needed to add a
  new measure that is a distinct count of TestNo 'Distinct Test Count'.
- Next I needed a measure of distinct count of positive tests,
- So I created a caluclated column that equals the TestNo when the row is Positive and NULL otherwise, called 'Count Positive Unadjusted'
- This measure counts NULLs and I could not adjust the NULL processing of the measure to fix this.
- So I added a new calculated field on the table 'Negative Result', the logical inverse of the Positive column
- Next I needed a measure Max of the Negative column, called 'Contains NULL'
- Next I needed a calculated measure that = `[Measures].[Count Positive Unadjusted] - [Measures].[Contains NULL]`, called 'Positive Test Count'
- My ratio calculate can then become `[Measures].[Positive Test Count]/[Measures].[Distinct Test Count]`